# Excel VBA - Prevent Editing after Date and Force Enable Macros

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a Workbook that I want to make read-only/protect after a certain date.  I also want to force the user to have macros enabled.  So far I have the following script, but despite changing it to read-only it doesn't seem to do anything.  I have also tried to enable protection on the sheets after that date, but am getting errors.  Can anyone help me out?

-Eric

```
Private Const ExpirationDate As Date = #4/5/2099#

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Timebomb
    If CDate(Now) >= CDate(ExpirationDate) Then
        ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess (xlReadOnly)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet").Protect Password:="NoAccess", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="NoAccess", UserInterfaceOnly := True
    End If

    ' Force Enable Macros
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("START").Visible = xlVeryHidden

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet").Activate
End Sub

' Force Enable Macros
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Sheets("START").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't force macros to run because ...then there is no point to having any security on macros at all. What you can do is have your users add your folder as a trusted network location

```
Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings...>Trusted Locations
Allow Trusted Locations on my network
add New location...
```

Alternatively, you can have a script you run that "archives" the old files (puts them in some other folder) and makes a PDF of them in place of the original. The PDF would be the 'read-only' version.